# How to use celery with django and redis [Errno 61]

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

its my first time using celery and redis. I'm not sure if my configurations are correct but its giving me an OSError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

**celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'IrisOnline.settings')

app = Celery('order_management')


# Using a string here means the worker don't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
  app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


 @app.task(bind=True)
   def debug_task(self):
     print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

**settings.py**

```
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Manila'
```

**__init__.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

**function I want to execute**

```
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(hour=10, minute=15))
def print_something(root_product):
    print("something")
```

Comment: It's a linux? can you run netstat -putan | grep 6379?

Comment: How did you start redis? Is it actually running on port 6379 of localhost?

Comment: the beat is running and it says broker is redis///localhost:6379// I'm just wondering why my periodic task is not working